# Find all solutions of a PDE (Poisson problem)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

> Consider the Neumann problem
>   $$\Delta u = c, \qquad x \in \Omega = B(\mathbf{x},1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$$
>   equipped with the boundary condition $\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = 1 \quad \forall x \in \partial \Omega$ where $c$ is a constant.
>
> Find all $c$ for which there exists a solution and find all these solutions.

The boundary condition suggests usage of the Green theorem:
$$\int_\Omega \varphi \Delta u = - \int \nabla \varphi \nabla u + \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n}$$

Which results in
$$c \int_\Omega\varphi = - \int \nabla \varphi \nabla u + \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi$$
If I would take $\varphi = u$ then this results in 
$$\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2} = \int_{\partial \Omega} u - c \int_\Omega u$$

But how could I continue? I don't really see how to reach a answer to the question. I guess I would look for a upper bound of $c$?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG we may assume $\bf x = 0$, i.e. $\Omega$ is the unit disk centred at $0$.  Since everything is rotationally invariant, if there is a solution there is one that has radial symmetry.  The radially symmetric solutions of $\Delta u = c$ are $u(r,\theta) = f(r) = c r^2/4 + a \ln(r) + b$, and for this to be continuous at $r=0$ we need $a=0$.  Then we want $f'(1) = c/2 = 1$.  So we need $c=2$, in which case $u(r,\theta) = r^2/2 + b$ is a solution.  Now all you have to do is show that these are all the solutions.

Comment: I have already shown that the problem $\Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$, $\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = g$ on $\Gamma$ has a unique solution up to a constant. Which would imply here $u(r,\theta) = \frac{r^2}{2} + b$ to be unique up to constant which is taken care of through the $b$. I guess this would be valid :)

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but taking $φ = 1$, we directly get
$$
c = \frac{|\partial \Omega|}{|\Omega|}
$$
which in the case of a ball of dimension $2$ is $c=\frac{2\pi}{\pi} = 2$.